# ProcessMaker on Centos 7 doesn't find mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, centos7, processmaker

I'm having trouble getting ProcessMaker running on CentOS 7. I've got through the [CentOS 7 installation](http://wiki.processmaker.com/3.0/ProcessMaker_CentOS/RHEL_Installation) and have all of the [prerequisites](http://wiki.processmaker.com/index.php/3.0/ProcessMaker_Installation_Requirements). I've modified my virtual hosts file to look like this:

```
NameVirtualHost my.host.com
<VirtualHost my.host.com:80>
    ServerName my.host.com

    DocumentRoot /opt/processmaker/workflow/public_html
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

    <Directory /opt/processmaker/workflow/public_html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride none
        Order allow,deny
        Require all granted
        Allow from all

        ExpiresActive On

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^.*/(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L,NC]
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I receive the following error message:

> ```
> Sistem Configuration Error:
> Please review your apache virtual host configuration file, and be sure you have the following rules:
>
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
>     RewriteEngine On
>     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app.php [QSA,L]
> </IfModule>
> ```

I've verified that mod_rewrite is installed and loaded:

```
# ls /etc/httpd/modules | grep mod_rewrite
mod_rewrite.so
# grep rewrite /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-base.conf 
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

```
<VirtualHost *:9999>
    ServerName 127.0.0.1

    DocumentRoot /opt/processmaker/workflow/public_html
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

    <Directory /opt/processmaker/workflow>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
      RewriteEngine On
         RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
         RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app.php [QSA,L]
      ExpiresActive On
      ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 day"
      ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 day"
      ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 day"
      ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 day"
      ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 day"
      ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 day"

    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

I still don't understand why this was happening, but reinstalling everything slightly differently fixed it. The major change was using the default PHP installation, but adding the current EPEL repository to get php_mcrypt, but otherwise following the stock installation instructions. I don't see any good reason why this would have changed anything, but it now works.